# Cant play video in my ios app

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, xcode9.2

I want to have video player in my ios application (I work with xcode version 9.2 and swift version 4). It must play m3u8 video from internet. I use the code below for this:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewControllerPlayer: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {            
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let videoURL = URL(string: "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")
        let video = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
        let videoPlayer = AVPlayerViewController()
        videoPlayer.player = video
        present(videoPlayer, animated: true, completion: {
            video.play()
        })

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }
}
```

but unfortunately after compile my app crashes and doesnt play video. Then I transfered code from `viewDidLoad()` method to `viewDidAppear()`. But there is no effect. So, how can i play video from internet in my ios app? Thanks.

Comment: check your console, are you getting something like: `App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file` ?

Comment: Andrea Mugnaini, yes, you are right

Comment: Don't call present in the `viewDidLoad` since it might not be shown yet thus it will not be able to present anything.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for `present` method says the following about `completion`:

The block to execute after the presentation finishes. This block has no return value and takes no parameters. You may specify nil for this parameter.

Move `video.play()` above `present` and it should work.

However you are using HTTP, so ATS will complain about it and won't show video.

Add (BAD PRACTICE) the following code to your `Info.plist` to disable ATS:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
   <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
   <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: unfortunately, it doesnt help :(